# Magento2 Order Date is Wrong in Admin Grid

Tags: magento2, sales-order, date

We created an order in magento2 with API calls. It is working fine as expected .

> We have `created_at` field date as `23-01-2020 12:12:12` in database where
>   as in admin magento2 order grid it is showing as Order Date as    Jan 23,
>   2020, 5:42:12 PM . Which is not matching with database value. How can
>   i resolve this?

In Magento2 Store , ***I selected the Time Zone as India/Kolkata***

Answer (score 0):

This is intended behaviour in Magento. Magento saves the date in GMT format, and whenever it displays in frontend or admin panel it will convert to the selected timezone.

In your case display will be GMT+5:30 when considering Indian time.